# Place the Dropdown List in for each of ko databind

Tags: knockout.js

```
Shall I get any sample to place the Dropdown List in for each of ko databind.something like give below


<div data-bind="foreach:valuelist>
<select data-bind ="options :valuelist value =selecteditem></select>
</div>
```

Is that any sample like this ?

Comment: knockoutjs documentation site should be the first place to see: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Comment: yes but inside the for each value property of drop down not works

Comment: I cannot figure out what you want to do. Normally, you don't need a "foreach" when using "options". The "options" binding is enough. This should work: <select data-bind ="options: valuelist, value: selecteditem"></select>

Comment: posted the full requirement in the topic "Ko template with for each to repeat the same drop down in the loop"

Answer (score 2):

I've created some example in jsFiddle **[Click Here to see an example](http://jsfiddle.net/pkysylevych/LqY6J/)**. 



So in general, you should do the following: 
1. For example create some observableArray with name values:

```
self.values = ko.observableArray([ "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"]);
```

2. Add your html like this one:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'myTemplate', foreach: values}">
</div>

<script id="myTemplate" type="text/html">
  <select data-bind="options: $root.values, optionsCaption: 'Choose..'"></select>
</script>
```

Hope it will help you.