# foreach:$data and change the $data

Tags: knockout.js

I have an arrayList, for example BallonColor = {red,Green}
So I need to create 2 times the dropdownbox  and if i have 5 colors then i need to have 5 dropdown list with all 5 items as options in all the dropdown

How it can be achieved in knockouts

I tried the following code.. taken foreach:$data (ie for each item)
but when on changing the value of the dropdown the binded $index and $data not changed

```
<div data-bind = "foreach:$data" class="row">
                <div class="col">  
                    <select id ="SELECT" data-bind="options:$parent, optionsText: 'AttributeName', optionsValue: 'Id', optionsCaption: 'Select Attribute...',value : SelectedAttribute"></select>
                    <div data-bind="template: { name: function() { return templateName($parent,$data,SelectedAttribute) } }"></div>
                    <div>
                        <span>with any of the following values:</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <a href="#"  id = "List"   class="link">List</a> | <a href="#"  id= "Range" class="link">Range</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is similar to [THIS question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267662/place-the-dropdown-list-in-for-each-of-ko-databind/13515179#13515179) where I've already answered (probably).

Please, have a look on this and let me know the results.

Thanks.

Comment: yip, template is the way to go.

Comment: but in that example , I can get one item in dropdown because of foreach:values. i want all the values in all dropdown

Comment: I am using List<List<type>> and hence $data in the least level array type